# npm module install locally only if not available globally

Tags: git, npm, installation, global, local

We have a web project that has multiple `git submodules` within each other. For functional testing, we use both `PhantomJS` and `Selenium` (one for local development, the other for CI deployment and Visual Regression Testing).

Because each submodule has it's own `package.json`, `PhantomJS` and `selenium-standalone` are installed multiple times during the bootstrap process.

My question is this: Can I install these giant `npm` modules globally and somehow have my application pick up the global installation and only when this is unavailable, try and pull from cache or from the remote repo?

Something like:

`if(global_install){
 continue
}
else{
 npm install
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a solution can be what RedSpar0w proposed here: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2949#issuecomment-238703924

```
{
    "name": "Meh",
    "description": "Some Description",
    "scripts": {
        "preinstall": "(npm list someDependency -g && npm install otherDependency -g) || (npm list someDependency || npm install someDependency) && npm install otherDependency -g"
    }
}
```

checks if `someDependency` installed globally if so then install otherDependency globally
otherwise check if `someDependency` installed locally if not then install someDependency locally but either way install otherDependency globally because someDependency is not installed locally

You can play with it depending on your needs.